# How do I set my first file in a directory to a variable in TCL?

Tags: tcl

I want to set the first file in my directory to a variable, how do I do it?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
   set files [glob "./programming/.business_files/*.txt"]
   set first_file $files[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line with `glob` is right, but the order is not determined (it's whatever the OS system calls spit it out in, and those guarantee *nothing* about order in general). Thus, you'll probably want to `lsort` the list of filenames. The `-dictionary` option is highly recommended for this; it produces the order that users usually think of as the natural order of filenames.

```
set files [lsort -dictionary [glob "./programming/.business_files/*.txt"]]
```

Then you can get the first one with `lindex` (because Tcl uses `[`…`]` for command substitutions, not indexing).

```
set first_file [lindex $files 0]
```

Comment: You might also want the `-nocase` option to that `lsort` call.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep (for some reason) the array approach, a slightly less than ideal solution is:

```
set n 0
foreach file [lsort -dictionary [glob "./programming/.business_files/*.txt"]] {
    set files($n) $file
    incr n
}

set first_file $files(0)
```

That said, the `lindex` solution above is the cleanest.

Bye